# RestSharp -Trying two consecutive posts

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, restsharp

I am trying to perform two posts one after the other using Restsharp. Below is my code

```
_settings.Request.AddJsonBody(new Posts() { emailAddress = _settings.sharedEmailAddress, passwordPlainText = _settings.sharedPassword, siteId = _settings.sharedSiteId });

_settings.Response = _settings.RestClient.ExecutePostAsync<Posts>(_settings.Request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

_settings.sharedSiteId = secondSiteId;

_settings.Request.AddJsonBody(new Posts() { emailAddress = _settings.sharedEmailAddress, passwordPlainText = _settings.sharedPassword, siteId = _settings.sharedSiteId});

_settings.ResponseSecondPost = _settings.RestClient.ExecutePostAsync<Posts>(_settings.Request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The difference between first and fourth line is that the `_settings.sharedSiteId` is different. But only the first post is successful and the second one is not? Anyone knows why this happens? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by changing the fourth line to

```
_settings.RequestSecondPost.AddJsonBody(new Posts() { emailAddress = _settings.sharedEmailAddress, passwordPlainText = _settings.sharedPassword, siteId = _settings.sharedSiteId});
```